# Can't figure how to use customize the webchat?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a chatbot from Cognigy.ai. I made a small bot but I am not able to customize it's webchat interface from the Github repo, but I am not able to figure out how to do it?

This is the endpoint of my chatbot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      html {
        background-color: #eee;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- 1. Load the webchat.js bundle via a script tag -->
    <script src="https://github.com/Cognigy/WebchatWidget/releases/download/v2.20.0/webchat.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize the Webchat towards a Cogngiy Endpoint via initWebchat() -->
    <script>
      initWebchat(
        "https://endpoint-trial.cognigy.ai/8a8b023c1da283e1c9191c471aaef8dc5090ccc8f33d6a39b00a80276754309e",
        {
          userId: "documentation-reader",
          forceWebsockets: true
        }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to remove the 'Powered by Cognigy AI' line from the webchat interface. In the Github repo they mentioned that I need to disableBranding = True. But where should I write it?

The Github repo for customization is:
https://github.com/Cognigy/WebchatWidget/blob/master/docs/embedding.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this,

```
<script>
    initWebchat(
      "https://endpoint-trial.cognigy.ai/8a8b023c1da283e1c9191c471aaef8dc5090ccc8f33d6a39b00a80276754309e",
        {
          settings: {
            colorScheme: "#fab",
            disableBranding: true
          }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `title` contains strings, so will it be `title: Hello World' or `title = Hello World`?

Comment: @JohnPaul it will be `title: "Hello World"` (With double quotes.)

Comment: `title: "Hello World"`

Comment: Thank you @PersonWhoIsStuck and @Vinay!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
settings: {
  disableBranding: true
}
```

after the line:

```
forceWebsockets: true,
```

make sure you add a comma after `forceWebsockets: true` = `forceWebsockets: true,`

As it is mentioned in their documentation:
Name: Settings | Type: Endpoint Settings

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it how to do it.